# user control vs custom control

Tags: asp.net

i want to know where user controls should be used and where custom control should be.in what ways they can be best used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667 goes through it all

Comment: For a quick summary of the differences http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710%28v=vs.71%29.aspx it explains "The main differences between the two types... in [a] table"

Answer (score 0):

User controls are better than custom controls because it allows you to create your own complex items.

Comment: Can you explain this any more?